# Boost.Test custom test summary

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

Is there a way to read the test results (all assertions that either passed ot failed) at runtime using Boost Unit Testing framework ?

What I want is to produce custom test log and output it to the console in a custom human readable format after each test I run.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to have Boost.Test output XML, which you then parse and translate to your custom format.  Use the [`report_format` and related options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html) to set the format and the level.